# How to add new action into Devise registrations controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding

I know how to override default controllers and it is working, but now I need to add new action into Registrations controller.

I need to update user fields. I need to add First and Last name in this form, but I don't want to use standard edit page, because it will be separate page.

So I need other page. I have paypal..html.erb in my registrations folder, but I can't render it from action in regustrations controller.

Paypal action:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def paypal  
end 
...
end
```

routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :sessions => 'sessions'} do
    match 'paypal' => 'registrations#paypal'
  end
```

but somehow it render new registration file. Here is error:

```
   NoMethodError in Registrations#paypal
   Showing C:/1508/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #22 raised:
```

**How I can use update form to do this and what I'm doing wrong ?**

Comment: what devise version are you using? Try to use `devise_scope :user { match 'paypal' => 'registrations#paypal' } ` instead of passing block to the `devise_for`

Comment: Last version. I will try, but I found other stupid solution) I just created new controller)

Comment: Other error: `SyntaxError  E:/1708/config/routes.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end
  devise_scope :user { match 'paypal' => 'registrations#paypal' }`

Comment: I mean `devise_scope(:user) { match 'paypal' => 'registrations#paypal' }`

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my routes to make it work

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'paypal(/:id)', :action => 'paypal', :controller => 'user/registrations', :as => 'paypal'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little unclear, however Why not explicitly render the view?

```
def paypal
    render 'devise/registrations/paypal' 
end
```

If you have multiple type of users it may be better to separate out the paths and routing.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-routes-to-user-registration-pages